# Получение списка аргументов метода в аспекте

Tags: java, spring

Гарантирован ли порядок возвращения агрументов метода в аспекте?
То есть, если функция имеет вид:

```
public void foo (Integer i1, Integer i2, String s1){...}
```

то

```
ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint = ...;      
Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
```

вернет тот же порядок аргументов:

```
args[0] ->i1
args[1] ->i2
args[2] ->s1
```